# How to get the maximum value among the arguments of class objects in Python?

Tags: python, class, class-method, python-class, class-instance-variables

I have sample class and instances:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, num)

#instances
a = A(2)
b = A(4)
c = A(5)
d = A(7)
```

In another class (class B) within a method, I have to get the highest value among the arguments `2,4,5,7` because I need it for a conditional statement. But I'm having a hard time coding because the instances were put in a list. That is,

```
lst = [a,b,c,d]
```

So,

```
class B:
  def __init__(self, point_list)

  def com()
    x = 0
    while x < max(other_class.point_list.num)

lst = [a,b,c,d]
other_class = B(lst)
```

From `def com()`, I need `7` to be the max value I am comparing to x but I don't know how I can get it. My code was wrong. I don't even know if the max function is to be used.

The error that pops when I use the max function is:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'num'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate over the list and get the maximum element

```
>>> 
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self, point_list):
...             self.pl = point_list
...     def com(self):
...             return max(self.pl, key=lambda x:x.num).num
... 
>>> other_class = B(lst)
>>> other_class.com()
7
```

Comment: Or `return max(x.num for x in self.pl)` instead of `return max(self.pl, key=lambda x:x.num).num`

Comment: @Stef yeah, we can also do that, this is more neat then mine

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `key` argument of `max()`. Also, if you want to call `other_class.com()` to get the maximum value, then the function `com()` has to have a `self` argument:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, num):
      self.num = num

#instances
a = A(2)
b = A(4)
c = A(5)
d = A(7)

class B:
  def __init__(self, point_list):
    self.point_list = point_list

  def com(self):
    x = 0
    while x < max(self.point_list, key=lambda n: n.num):
        # Code goes here

lst = [a,b,c,d]
other_class = B(lst)
```

The `key=lambda n: n.num` makes max() return the A instance with the highest `.num`.
Also, `__init__` is a function, so it needs a colon after it, and you need to assign `self.num = num` and `self.point_list = point_list`

Comment: It's probably better to write `max_x = max(self.point_list, key=attrgetter('num')); x = 0; while x = max_x: ...` to avoid redoing the `max` calculation at every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Also note that `max([A(2), A(7)])` will return `A(7)`, ***not*** just `7`, so at least it should be `x < max(self.point_list).num`, not `x < max(self.point_list)`. Or you can do instead: `x < max(map(attrgetter('num'), self.point_list))`

Answer (score -1):

It is confusing what you want but from what I understand is you want to find max value of `point_list`. You can do the following:

```py
class B:
  def __init__(self, point_list):
    self.point_list = point_list

  def com(self):
    x = 0
    while x < max(self.point_list):
        pass

lst = [a,b,c,d]
other_class = B(lst)
```

Comment: If you want to use inheritance then the logic will be different.

Comment: your function still not giving the max value

Comment: Did you call `com()`?

You need to call it like `other_class.com()`